# How to fix this ' float not iterable ' Error

Tags: python, loops, conditional-statements

I'm Solving the Problem set of MIT's introduction to programming.

```
def compute_deriv(poly):
    """
    Computes and returns the derivative of a polynomial function. If the
    derivative is 0, returns (0.0,).
    """

    der = ()
    for ele in poly :
        if poly.index(ele) == 0 :
            continue
        else:
            der += tuple(ele*float(poly.index(ele)))
    return der

poly = (-13.39, 0.0, 17.5, 3.0, 1.0)    # x^4 + 3x^3 + 17.5x^2 - 13.39

print compute_deriv(poly)
```

why the program is trying to iterate over this line? and return the error not iterable? it shouldn't be so

```
der += tuple(ele*float(poly.index(ele)))
```

Comment: You're calling `tuple()` with a float as an argument, and you can't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python is interpreting

```
tuple(ele*float(poly.index(ele)))
```

as a *cast*, rather than as a *wrapper*. You're giving it one argument, and it's assuming that that argument is an iterable object that you want to reformat into a tuple. In fact, you actually want to create a one-element tuple containing the object. This can happen with lists and sets, too, and I suspect if you did either of the following:

```
list(ele*float(poly.index(ele)))
set(ele*float(poly.index(ele)))
```

you'd see the same error as you're currently experiencing.

---

The simplest solution to this is to simply use a `tuple` literal, rather than the `tuple()` function:

```
der += (ele*float(poly.index(ele)),)
```

(for clarity, `(value,)` is the syntax for a 1-element tuple, because just parentheses would be ambiguous. If you want to be *maximally* clear, you could just use a list instead most of the time - a list literal is just `[]` and a set literal is `{}`)

Comment: I wouldn't call it a cast. [`tuple()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuples) creates a new `tuple` object by calling the class constructor, which always takes an iterable.

Comment: @dhke excellent point, I edited the start of my answer accordingly. I'm not sure if there's a better way to articulate that in the body, but if you think there is one go ahead and edit the post to include it, thanks